# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method load(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest;

Tags: android, carousel, android-glide

I am using this library for carousel view. And it loads data very nicely in a sample project that i have created. But the main project in which i have to use this is giving this error:

> 2019-03-09 18:10:45.536 26901-26901/com.winds.partner
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.winds.partner, PID: 26901
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method load(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest; in
>   class Lcom/bumptech/glide/RequestManager; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager' appears in
>   /data/app/com.winds.partner-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)

I am using glide library in this main project of mine, i think its with the latest version of glide maybe. I cannot remove glide, because i am also using gif images in some places with the help of glide.

I have tried downgrading glide version to 4.3.1 , still throwing this error with crash when i am using that slider library.

Comment: `split_lib_dependencies_apk` Are you using instant run or something?

Comment: Hey i have that hot reload/quick apply button enabled on android studio.

Comment: What version of Android Studio and Android Gradle Plugin? What version of Android on device? Did you enable multidex? Have you tried full run (without apply changes)?